# Cannot run UIAutomator tests in latest version of Android SDK

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I've upgraded to latest version of **Android Studio (1.5)** and SDK and now my **UIAutomator** tests, run from ant, don't work anymore (they used to, till Android Studio 1.0.x).

This is the script I use to run tests:

```
@echo off

cls

set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

cmd /c ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\thirdparty\ant\bin\ant build

if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end

:run

cmd /c adb push ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\app\libs\uiautomator.jar /data/local/tmp
cmd /c adb push .\bin\MyTestsUIAutomatorTest.jar /data/local/tmp

cmd /c adb shell uiautomator runtest MyTestsUIAutomatorTest.jar -c xxxxxx.haylugar.uiautomator.src.SettingsActivityUIAutomatorTest
cmd /c adb shell uiautomator runtest HayLugarUIAutomatorTest.jar -c xxxxxx.haylugar.uiautomator.src.ParkingListActivityUIAutomatorTest
cmd /c adb shell uiautomator runtest HayLugarUIAutomatorTest.jar -c xxxxx.haylugar.uiautomator.src.ParkingDetailActivityUIAutomatorTest
```

When building with ant, uiautomator.jar objects are not found:

```
src\ParkingDetailActivityUIAutomatorTest.java:3: error: package com.android.uiautomator.core does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
```

Apparently, instructions have been changed according to [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/start/index.html#run-instrumented-tests), but I followed them and they are missing something (I get an error when running tests saying that "no tests found to run"). Anyway, I just want to run my tests the same way I used to! I don't want to change configurations and waste time with the new nitty britty idea of the Android SDK team...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I needed to edit manually the build.xml to overwrite the compile and the dex targets of the uibuild.xml provided by the SDK to do the job correctly, copying the required libraries (uiautomator.jar and junit.jar) somewhere in my project structure:

```
    <property name="jar.libs.dir" value="../../../../../../libs" />
<property name="jar.libs.absolute.dir" location="${jar.libs.dir}" />
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.absolute.dir}">
        <include name="uiautomator.jar" />
        <include name="junit-4.12.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<!-- version-tag: VERSION_TAG -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/uibuild.xml" />


<!-- overwrite the compile target in uibuild.xml to include to external 
    jars -->
<target name="compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-compile">
    <javac encoding="${java.encoding}" source="${java.source}"
        target="${java.target}" debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
        destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
        verbose="${verbose}" fork="${need.javac.fork}">
        <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
        <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- overwrite the -dex target in uibuild.xml to include external jar files 
    into the target dex file. -->
<target name="-dex" depends="compile, -post-compile">
    <dex executable="${dx}" output="${intermediate.dex.file}"
        nolocals="@{nolocals}" verbose="${verbose}">
        <path path="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" />
    </dex>
</target>

</project>
```